# How to compare multiple columns within a dataset in R?

Tags: r

My dataset is something like this..it has many more rows and columns than this:

```
           x1       x2      x3      x4
part 1      1       1       1       1
part 2      0       1       1       0
part 3      0       0       0       1
part 4      1       0       1       1
part 5      1       1       1       1
```

I want to compare the columns in various combinations(x1 x2,x1 x3,x1 x4,x1 x2 x3,x1 x2 x4,x1 x3 x4,x2 x3 x4,x1 x2 x3 x4) to find the maximum number of parts common.

I can use combn to get various combinations of columns but I dont know how to compare various columns. all.equal requires 2 different datasets where as I want to compare various columns within a single dataset. I am a beginner.Please give me suggestions. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please do not post data using a picture. In text it is easier to reproduce.

Comment: ok sure...I am new to stackoverflow.Thanks

Comment: @MounikaBandhakavi just for future reference, just paste the output of `dput(df)`. Thats the best way to paste data for R!

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan ok sure.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use `outer`. Here, a helper function `comp_cols` is defined which takes two vectors of column names and calculates if the correponding columns of `dat` are equal.

```
# slightly modified data.frame from question
dat <- data.frame(x1=c(1,0,0,1,1), x2=c(1,1,0,0,1), x3=c(1,1,0,1,1), x4=c(1,0,0,1,1))

# compare function
comp_cols <- function(x,y) {
    ans <- rep(NA, length(x))
    for (i in seq_along(x)) ans[i] <- all(dat[,x[i]]==dat[,y[i]])
    return(ans)
}

# compare each combination
res <- outer(colnames(dat), colnames(dat), FUN=comp_cols)
rownames(res) <- colnames(dat)
colnames(res) <- colnames(dat)
```

This is probably not the most efficient solution, as the result matrix is symmetric and hence only half the calculations are required. If computation time is an issue, the use of `combn` might be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!!

Comment: How can I compare 3 or more than 3 columns at once.....is ther any function that can do this? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: As far as I know there is no function for that. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "maximum number of parts common" in your question? I.e. what would be the expected answer given your data.frame? part1, part5? In that case my answer is not correct.